# Individually limit disk storage size for queues in ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

Is it possible for ActiveMQ using KahaDB to limit the storage size for persistent queues individually?

---

We are using a setup like this with ActiveMQ for data exchange between the applications:

`[App1] ==> (Queue1) ==> [App2] ==> (Queue2) ==> [App3]`

The data flow is from App1 to App2 via Q1 (persistent), then from App2 to App3 via Q2 (also persistent). Now, the messages from Q1 are deleted when App2 acknowledges them, from Q2 when App3 does it. The problem arises when App1 fills up the queue when App2 is not available. Then, when it is available again, App2 takes the buffered messages and tries to send them to App3, but due to some overhead the messages put into Q2 are larger than those on Q1, and App2 only ACKs messages on Q1 when they are successfully put into Q2 and blocks until the later is possible. So, the system is in a deadlock as no messages are taken out of Q1 and Q2.

Now, one solution to this problem that came into our mind is to limit the storage space of the queues individually (e.g. Q1 and Q2 each use 10 GB), so that a full Q1 does not interfere with Q2, but we were not able to configure ActiveMQ to do this, not with mKahaDB (still the same deadlocks) or using Producer Flow Control. Almost all settings we have found are used for memory, and don't seem to be applicable to disk storage. Is there a way to achieve this separation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While no configuration to limit the actual disk storage use per queue seems to exist, by using different `storeUsageHighWaterMark` destination policies for the different queues we are able avoid the deadlock, as there is now always some reserved space for Q2.

Answer (score 0):

You should use flowcontrol to stop accepting messages in Q1 based on your threshold pending message count, that way Q2 can still continue. You could also use different KahaDB files for your queues Q1 and Q2(if your activeMQ version supports it)
There is no control available(yet) on the DB file size.